# Define imports and Python project structure to allow running locally and when installed

Tags: python

I am working on a Python project and started using a setup.py file to install it. I followed some guides on how to structure the project and everything is working great after installing it.

My problem is that I "lost" the ability to run my application from inside the project's directory, locally so to speak without installing it, for testing purposes. Here's how the directory layout looks like:

```
project_dir/
├── bin
│   └── app.py
├── data
│   └── data.conf
├── app_module
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

The problem has to do with the imports. In `app.py` I have `import app_module` and it works as intended after it gets installed to the proper directory by running `python setup.py install`. If I want to run it by doing `python bin/app.py` it obviously doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how could I get this to work? Ideally I want to be able to run it from inside the directory and it should still work when installed with the `setup.py` script.

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at relative imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is either set the python path to include your module (ie run it as `PYTHONPATH=project_dir python app.py`, or make the `app_module` be placed in `project_dir/bin` in order to be included in the builtin path.

Note that not doing this is dangerous as after installed your `app.py` would otherwise pick up the installed package (`app_module`) instead of that in your project dir (which can get confusing).

Comment: Using PYTHONPATH is surprisingly simple and solved my problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if your `bin/app.py` is only doing:

```
import app_module
app_module.run() # or whatever you called the main() function
```

you could (should!) use an [`entry_points` (search for `console_scripts`)](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins).

And while running your uninstalled code, you would do either:

`python -m app_module` or `python app_module/__init__.py` (assuming you have a `__main__` section inside this file, otherwise look at how [`json.tool`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/62235755609f/Lib/json/tool.py) is doing.

### Edit

Here is a basic example, assuming your library is named "app_module".

#### setup.py

```
import imp
import os
import setuptools

module_name = 'app_module'
module = imp.load_module(
    module_name,
    *imp.find_module(module_name, [os.path.dirname(__file__)])
)

base = 'data'
data_files = [
    (
        '/usr/local/share/appdata/' + module_name + root[len(base):],
        [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files]
    ) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base)
]

setuptools.setup(
    name=module_name,
    version=module.__version__,
    classifiers=(
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux',
    ),
    packages=(
        module_name,
    ),
    entry_points={
        # the executable will be called 'app' (not 'app.py')
        'console_scripts': ['app = ' + module_name + ':main'],
        # it does not seems unnecessarily complicated to me, it's just three lines
    },
    data_files=data_files,
)
```

#### app_module/__init__.py

```
import optparse
import sys

__version__ = '1.2.3'

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(version=__version__)
    parser.add_option('-m', '--man', action='store_true')

    opt, args = parser.parse_args()

    if opt.man:
        help(__name__)
        sys.exit()

    print opt, args


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### And now...

To run it:

```sh
python /full-or-replative/path/to/app_module/__init__.py
# or
export PYTHONPATH=/full-or-replative/path/to/app_module/
python -m app_module
```

To install and run it:

```sh
# test in a virtualenv
workon test
python setup.py install
app -h
```

Comment: I looked into entry_points and managed to get it to work, but it seems unnecessarily complicated for my rather simple package.

I tried `pyhon -m app_module` and `app_module/__init__.py` which at first didn't work. Creating a `app_module/__main__.py` file which called my main function and running `pyhon -m app_module` worked.
Did you actually mean that file when you said `__main__` section or were you referring to having a `if __name__ == "__main__":` in my `__init__.py` file? Having the latter didn't work, I had to move it to the `__main__.py` file.

Comment: Yes, that cleared it up and it works.  

What I meant with more complicated is having to install setuptools, since distutils doesn't have entry_points, moving the main function to my module and using that slightly more complicated - automatically generated executable, etc.   
Exporting the project's directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable is just easier, and doesn't require me to touch anything else.  

Thank you for mentioning the entry_points feature, it might come in useful later on.